# The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Attempting to pull values from model in Json Post to use Autocomplete get this error at break point

> The specified type member 'SuggPromise' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

here is the Model

```
  public string SuggPromise
    {
        get
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }
```

And here is the Json Request

```
  public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
    {
        var promises = promiseRepository.Promises
            .Where(r => r.Title.Contains(term))
            .Take(10)
            .Select(r => new { label = r.SuggPromise});
        return Json(promises, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use properties that are mapped to database columns in LINQ-To-Entities expressions. `SuggPromise` doesn't seem to be one. Either use:

```
yadda.blah.Select(r => new { label = r.Title })
```

to do the projection in EF; or

```
yadda.blah.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { label = r.Title })
```

to fetch the entities whole, and then do the projection with LINQ-To-Objects.